# Trying to split an array into an arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to split a file I have read into an array. The file I am reading from is orderd like this.

- Lauri Maranto;manager
- Everett Flanders;manager
- Rachel Cornforth;designer
- Rocco Burks;designer
- Larue Maddox;designer
- Carmelo Grunden;tester

So here I put every line in an array, now im trying to put them in an arrayList and they have to be splitted.

```
try {                                                          
   String bestand = "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\java oo labo's\\ProjectBeheer\\data\\personeel.csv";                             
   String[] lijnen = TextFile.readLines(bestand);
} catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println("error" + io.getMessage());
}
```

This is what I got but it only shows the latest value and then I get an error.

```
String[] items = null; 
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    items = lines[i].split(";");
}
List<String> itemList = Arrays.asList(items);
System.out.println(itemList);
```

Someane knows what I can do? thanks.

The Problem now is that only the latest data is in itemList.
This is the printout.

```
[Carmelo Grunden, tester]
```

Comment: Post the error you mention, please.

Comment: my bad, i added it.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error but my arraylist only saves the last value and not the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` loop you create a *new* `String` array (`items`) every iteration. You only create the `List` *after* the `for` loop, however, which means only the last iteration will be taken into account. Try changing your code to something like:

```
List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    for (String token : lines[i].split(";")) {
        itemList.add(token);
    }
}
System.out.println(itemList);
```

---

*Extended answer based on a comment.*

If your goal was more like how @Maurice mentioned in the comments then you'd change your code to:

```
List<String[]> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    itemList.add(line.split(";"));
}
```

If you want the name and job in separate lists you could do something like:

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> jobList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(";");
    nameList.add(tokens[0]);
    jobList.add(tokens[1]);
}
```

Since each name corresponds to one job it might be better to use a `Map` instead.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(";");
    map.put(tokens[0], tokens[1]);
}
```

This only connects names to jobs (not the other way around) and it also limits the use to *unique* names (since a `Map` cannot have two of the same key).

The best option is probably to create a class to hold this information.

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String job;

    public Employee(String name, String job) {
        this.name = name;
        this.job = job;
    }

    // Getters and setters omitted for brevity...
}
```

And then create the list like:

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(";");
    list.add(new Employee(tokens[0], tokens[1]));
}
```

Comment: this is adding each word in a seperate element of the arraylist. Doesn't he want to store each splitted array in an arraylist?

Comment: @Maurice not according to how his or her code is written. The line `Arrays.asList(items)` indicates the goal is to split each line and add all the tokens to a `List` as separate elements.

Comment: @Slaw this also does work, thanks. But it would maybe be better if I also could split them in an seperate arraylist for name and job.

Comment: @floriandewulf added more to my answer

Comment: @Slaw awesome, thanks. but how can I take date from the second token? list.add(new Employee(tokens[0], tokens[1]));
if I do list.get(1) or further it only gives tokens[0] back.

Comment: @floriandewulf I'm not sure I understand. You don't mention a "date" belonging to your data in your question. If there is a date then you would change the code to reflect that. Also, with the `Employee` option calling `list.get(index)` gives you an `Employee` instance. You would then call `getName()` and `getJob()` on the `Employee` to get the name and job, respectively. If you have another question you should [ask it as a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Slaw I meant job, my bad